# Make my discord.js bot to send a random picture from an array of images from my computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make my bot that sends a random picture from an array (list) of pictures that I have on my computer. However, when I try to create an embed to send the image it says:

```
C:\Users\47920\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.image.url: Scheme "./something.jpg" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\47920\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\47920\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/821475002938294316/messages',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400
```

My code is below:

```js
case "andreas":
  var imagges = ['./knife.jpg', './lestab.jpg', './sexy.jpg', './timeplann.jpg'];
  var imagge = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagges.length);
  let randomern = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('sheesh')
    .setAuthor('joBas')
    .setImage(String([imagges[imagge]]));
  message.channel.send(randomern);
  break;
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You should also post some code.

Comment: Here
`
case"andreas":
        var imagges = ["./knife.jpg", "./lestab.jpg", "./sexy.jpg", "./timeplann.jpg" ];
        var imagge = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagges.length);
        let randomern = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('sheesh')
            .setAuthor('joBas')
            .setImage(String([imagges[imagge]]))
        message.channel.send(randomern);

         break;
`

Comment: It's telling you the url needs to be web accessible though http/https

Comment: Yes, i know that charlietfl, but i can't have them on http/s, so is there a way to do it different

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post code there, correctly formatted.

Comment: `case"andreas": var imagges = ["./knife.jpg", "./lestab.jpg", "./sexy.jpg", "./timeplann.jpg" ]; var imagge = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagges.length); let randomern = new Discord.MessageEmbed() .setTitle('sheesh') .setAuthor('joBas') .setImage(String([imagges[imagge]])) message.channel.send(randomern); break;`

Comment: No worries, I've just edited your question and added your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setImage` only allows you to add an image hosted online (i.e. you need to provide a URL that starts with `http` or `https`). Luckily, you can upload a file from your computer using the [`attachFiles()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=attachFiles) method instead of the `setImage`.

```js
const random = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
const images = [
  './images/avatar1.png',
  './images/avatar2.png',
  './images/avatar3.png',
  './images/avatar4.png',
];

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Attach file')
  .setAuthor('joBas')
  .attachFiles([random(images)]);

message.channel.send(embed);
```

The problem with this is that it's not the same as setting the image using `.setImage()`. The image is not displayed in the embed, but right before it:

[image]

To solve this you can set the image to the newly uploaded image that can be accessed via `attachment://fileName.extension`. As you will need both the filename and the extension, you need to store the filenames without the path in the array and store the path in a different variable.

Check out the code below:

```js
const random = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
const images = [
  'avatar1.png',
  'avatar2.png',
  'avatar3.png',
  'avatar4.png',
];
// path where the images are
const path = './images/';
const randomImage = random(images);

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Attach file')
  .setAuthor('joBas')
  .attachFiles([`${path}${randomImage}`])
  .setImage(`attachment://${randomImage}`);

message.channel.send(embed);
```

As you can see on the image below, the attached image is no longer outside of the embed:

[image]